# Display multiple custom cells in a UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, custom-controls

I am using Xcode 4.2 on SnowLeopard, and my project is using storyboards. I am trying to implement a `UITableView` with 2 different custom cell types, `sessionCell`and `infoCell`. I can get the 2 types to appear within the same list, but now I have a new problem?! The `sessionCell` is displayed once, and then X number of `infoCells` are displayed after it - just as I wanted - except that the first `infoCell` is always overwritten by the `sessionCell`!

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.people count];
}

//inside cellForRowAtIndexPath
    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"sessionCell"];
} else {
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"infoCell"];
}
...
return cell;
```

I've tried to say `return array count + 1`, or even hardcoded `return 7` (it fits my example) but both are incorrect!

```
myObject *person = [self.people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Or does my problem lie in the above line? I've even tried `indexPath.row+1`...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question was very hard to understand, so I tried to improve the language and clarify a bit more. Please let me know if I got it wrong!

Comment: based on your description the problem is with the logic in the if / else lines.  first cell is a sessionCell then any other cells that follow are infoCells

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, the first `infoCell` (second `UITableView` row) should display the first person object's data, right?

Then it seems you want:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *sessionCellID = @"sessionID";
    static NSString *infoCellID = @"infoID";

    if( indexPath.row == 0 ) {
        SessionCellClass *cell = nil;
        cell = (SessionCellClass *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:sessionCellID];
        if( !cell ) {
            //  do something to create a new instance of cell
            //  either alloc/initWithStyle or load via UINib
        }
        //  populate the cell with session model
        return cell;
    }
    else {
        InfoCellClass *cell = nil;
        cell = (InfoCellClass *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:infoCellID];
        if( !cell ) {
            //  do something to create a new instance of info cell
            //  either alloc/initWithStyle or load via UINib
            // ...

            //  get the model object:
            myObject *person = [[self people] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];

            //  populate the cell with that model object
            //  ...
            return cell;
        }
    }
```

and you need to return `[[self people] count] + 1` for the row count:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self people] count] + 1;
}
```

so that the n'th row shows the (n-1)th data.

Comment: Thanks for the response Alan! Yes that is what I'm after, however when I adjust the code as per your suggestion, I'm getting no build issues, but SIGABRT when it runs. I've tried both lines together, and each one individually, and they all throw SIGABRT?!@#$

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the if else section it shows that the first row is an "sessionCell" and all other rows are "infoCells" what i think you want to do is make the first row an sessionCell, the second row an infoCell and all of the other rows peopleCells

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.people count] + 2; // Added two for sessionCell & infoCell
}

//inside cellForRowAtIndexPath
if(indexPath.row == 0) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"sessionCell"];
} else if (indexPath.row == 1 {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"infoCell"];
} else {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"personCell"];
    Person *person = [self.people objectAtIndex:index.path.row - 2];
}

...
return cell;
```

Better yet, I would try to make two different sell sections, one for info and one for people

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return section == 0 ? 2 : self.people.count
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell = nil;
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if(indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"sessionCell"];
            // configure session cell
        } else if (indexPath.row == 1 {
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"infoCell"];
            // configure info cell
        }
    } else {
         cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"infoCell"];
         Person *person = [self.people objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
         // configure person cell
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Richerd! Perhaps my code is a little misleading as I've yet to rename one of the cells. But for now I only have 2 custom cells, 'sessionCell' & 'infoCell' and I am currently seeing 1 'sessionCell' (correct) and 5 'infoCell's (incorrect, as I'm seeing people 2-6; #1 is missing!)
As with Alan's response, when I use
   return [self.people count] + 1;
&
    ...[self.people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row -1];
I'm getting SIGABRT when it runs!

I'd like to try the two different sections (sect1: session, sect2: people), but I've yet to look for some code examples to help me do this

Comment: according to your code.  1 session cell and 5 info cells is correct.  because your using if / else the first cell will ALWAYS be an session cell and all OTHER cells will be an info cell.

Comment: I added an example of how you would achieve this with multiple sections

Comment: Many thanks for all your help in this matter Richerd, I owe you a beer mate! I got it to work with 2 sections and now I can move onto other tasks in the project :)