# What is good practice for code to dynamically add content to View Controller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I essentially want to have the following scenario.

[image]

Very simply, each entry contains a number label, two header labels and two text fields.

Being new to iOS development, I'm not sure of an intelligent, simple way to do this. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great case for using a `UITableView`. Create a table and a cell prototype that has all the elements that you need (a number, fields for name and age, etc). Create also a different cell prototype for "add more". That would be the last cell in your table. Increment the number of cells when a new record gets added.

There are multiple tutorials online for UITableView. What you want to look for is how to set up and use 2 different cell types. See, for example, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551093/display-multiple-custom-cells-in-a-uitableview).

If you go with a table view as opposed to just adding some subviews, you get some useful features for free:

- scrolling, if you have a lot of records
- animated insertion of rows
- support for deleting rows/records
- easy customization of your list of records: headers, footers, sections.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this manually - there is no problem. Create UITextField, UILabel etc objects in the code, configure them to your liking and add them using

```
[view addSubview: ]
```

method

Answer (score 1):

**Case A:** 
If you are going to add limited number of this type of view

Create one viewController, add textField, label etc to view of this view controller.
Create new instance of this viewController when user clicks add button then use addSubview by refering previously added view's y position

**Case B :** If number is not limited you will need scroll, then tableView is best option

1. You will need to create custom cell with your labels and textfield
   OR 
   you can do same using prototype cell if you are using storyboard.
2. When user will click add button do this

//Update your datasoure for new cell

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

You can create add more view and set it as table footer as it will always stay at bottom, like this

```
table.tableFooterView = assignYourAddMoreViewHere;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would:

1. Create a scroll view - `UIScrollView`, set the size of this scroll to the size of your main view and add this scroll view to your main view.
2. Create a content view - `UIView`, set the width of this content view to the with your the scroll view.  But the height should be 0.  Set the scroll view in step one's `setContentSize:` to content view's size.  Add this content view as a subview of the scroll view.
3. Create an iVar to keep track of how many buttons set has been used.
4. Now every time the + button tapped, create buttons, labels, etc., use the iVar in 3 to calculate and adjust the frame for each buttons, labels, etc.
5. Adjust the content View's frame to make room for the new set of buttons, labels, etc. Update the scroll view's contentSize: to the content view's frame size.
6. Add those buttons, labels, etc. in step 4 to content View as subviews.