# How to apply different cell styles in the rows of a TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, row, tableview

I have a tableview with 1 section and 6 rows. I want to apply to the first row a custom cell style subclass of UITableViewCell, while the rest of the rows have the default UITableViewCell. When I run the app it won't show the content of the first row with custom cell style. I tried to use return cell2 which refers to the custom style in the first row instead of cell, but it still didn't work.

**imageCellCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface imageCellCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *view;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *prodimage;



@end
```

**imageCellCell.m**

```
#import "imageCellCell.h"

@implementation imageCellCell

@synthesize view;
@synthesize label1;
@synthesize label2;
@synthesize prodimage;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
        [self addSubview:view];

        // initiate image
        prodimage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,2, 180, 180)];

        // initiate label1 with position (10,10,150,20)
        label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,150,20)];

        // initiate label2 with position (170,10,150,20)
        label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170,10,150,20)];

        [view addSubview:prodimage];
        [view addSubview:label1];
        [view addSubview:label2];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

**tableviewcontroller.m**

```
    #import "ScannedProductControllerViewController.h"
    #import "imageCellCell.h"


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


NSString *CellIdentifier;
NSString *CellIdentifierimg;




UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

imageCellCell *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierimg];

if (cell2 == nil) {
    cell2 = [[imageCellCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierimg];

    }


    if (indexPath.row == 1) {

    } else if (indexPath.row == 2) {

    }

    switch ([indexPath row])
    {
        case 0:
        {

            [cell2.prodimage  setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"test1.jpg"]];    
            [cell2.label1 setText:@"text"];
            [cell2.label2 setText:@"more text"];


            cell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

            break;


        }
        case 1:
        {

            NSString *labelText = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = labelText;


            break;

        }

        case 2:
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Manufacturer";

            break;

        }

        case 3:
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Overall Score";

            break;


        }

        case 4:
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Description";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

            break;

        }

        case 5:
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Video";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

            break;


        }
            }

    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you return `cell` at all times. Instead, return `cell2` (`imageCellCell` instance) if the row is 0.

Made modification to your code (Note the code is not fully tested):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier;
    NSString *CellIdentifierimg;

    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (cell == nil) {
        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            cell = [[imageCellCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierimg];
        } else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
    }

    switch ([indexPath row])
    {
        case 0:
        {
            imageCellCell *firstRowCell = (imageCellCell *)cell;
            [firstRowCell.prodimage  setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"test1.jpg"]];
            [firstRowCell.label1 setText:@"text"];
            [firstRowCell.label2 setText:@"more text"];
            firstRowCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            NSString *labelText = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = labelText;
            break;
        }

        case 2:
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Manufacturer";
            break;
        }

        case 3:
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Overall Score";
            break;
        }

        case 4:
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Description";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
            break;
        }

        case 5:
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Video";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
            break;
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Also there is a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9551691/2920335).